# Symfony 2.2 Doctrine2 many-to-many relation insert query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine2 in Symfony 2.2. I have the following entities:

1. "User"
2. "OrganizationSupplier"

and m:n relation between those entities. Here is how it is in schema:

```
class User {
.....
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="OrganizationSupplier", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="User_Supplier",
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="organization_supplier_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $allowed_suppliers;
.....
}
```

and

```
class OrganizationSupplier
{
...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="allowed_suppliers")
     */
    private $users;
...
}
```

Here is m:n table created by Doctrine:

```
CREATE TABLE `User_Supplier` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `organization_supplier_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`organization_supplier_id`),
  KEY `IDX_31AFA1DDA76ED395` (`user_id`),
  KEY `IDX_31AFA1DD1A81C9F7` (`organization_supplier_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_31AFA1DD1A81C9F7` FOREIGN KEY (`organization_supplier_id`) REFERENCES `organizationsupplier` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_31AFA1DDA76ED395` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Here is the data for user id=638 from this m:n table:

```
user_id organization_supplier_id
638 618
638 620
638 622
638 624
638 626
638 628
638 630
638 632
638 634
638 636
```

Everything is fine up to this point.

Now the problem: I have a form in admin that modifies this m:n table by adding/removing records from it. From business logic perspective I need to assign/unassign suppliers to certain users from the list of suppliers assigned to organization (OrgaizationSupplier entity - see above)

Here is the code for this field of the form:

```
->add('allowed_suppliers', 'entity', array('class'=>'STMainBundle:OrganizationSupplier', 'multiple'=>true, 'expanded'=>true,
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('os')
                ->where('os.organization = :organization')
                ->setParameter(':organization', $user->getOrganization());
```

If I submit it with a checkbox checked, I'm getting an SQL exception, it tries to launch a query with swapped columns:

```
INSERT INTO User_Supplier (organization_supplier_id, user_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [638, 618]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sollod_new`.`user_supplier`, CONSTRAINT `FK_31AFA1DDA76ED395` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`))".
```

so it should be vice versa, [618, 638] and not as it tries [638,618].

I'm a newbie in symfony, so I'm trying to find the place where it builds this query on postack, to control this parameters order.

Does anyone know where I can find it?

**UPDATE:** [Here](http://wikisend.com/download/494772/dump.html) is ladybug dump of Request, User entity and Form. This is done right after $form->bind($request);

Thanks a lot

**UPDATE:** My bad, I forgot that schema is cached as well, the schema that I gave above was already the correct and fixed one:

```
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="organization_supplier_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
```

Initially these columns were swapped. I only had to clear dev/prod cache to make it work. Sorry about that

Comment: You probably don't want to solve your issue using a tweak. Could you add a dump of the User object hydrated by your form ?

Comment: @olivier.l: I added ladybug html dump - see the link at the bottom of the question

Comment: We need the code from your controller also please.

Comment: Guys, my apologies: see the update above, I just had to clear cache after fixing the model. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

It was a matter of cache. Initially the data model was wrong, I fixed it to be:

```
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="organization_supplier_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
```

and forgot to clear cache